# ERC20 contract reverted

Tags: solidity, gas, erc-20

Hello everybody i'v deployed a erc20 contract on the main network all work fine but when i send ether to the contract adress i have this error :  Warning! Error encountered during contract execution [Reverted]
i didn't understand why.
TxHash: 0x835d9b4106c279e116f97cc6038c6e12004aaac5408ac862436b0d8fc07ea94f 
contract adress : 0xACdDb1b4a5527af01ED85C74F43F90ecD1276b8E

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

It seems this condition is not met

```
require(balances[fundsWallet] >= amount);
```

I checked the rest of the contract code and you don't take into account the `msg.value` being in Wei, not ETH.

Your buy function

```
function() payable{
    totalEthInWei = totalEthInWei + msg.value;
    uint256 amount = msg.value * unitsOneEthCanBuy;
    require(balances[fundsWallet] >= amount);

    balances[fundsWallet] = balances[fundsWallet] - amount;
    balances[msg.sender] = balances[msg.sender] + amount;

    Transfer(fundsWallet, msg.sender, amount); // Broadcast a message to the blockchain

    //Transfer ether to fundsWallet
    fundsWallet.transfer(msg.value);                               
}
```

Should take into account that `msg.value` is in Wei

```
uint256 amount = msg.value * unitsOneEthCanBuy / 1000000000000000000;
```

And you don't need to emit the `Transfer()` event because it is already emitted in the `transfer()` function.

Thus your function should be

```
function() payable{
    totalEthInWei = totalEthInWei + msg.value;
    uint256 amount = msg.value * unitsOneEthCanBuy / 1000000000000000000;
    require(balances[fundsWallet] >= amount);

    balances[fundsWallet] = balances[fundsWallet] - amount;
    balances[msg.sender] = balances[msg.sender] + amount;

    //Transfer ether to fundsWallet
    fundsWallet.transfer(msg.value);                               
}
```

Comment: Hello thanks for your response, i have to change my contract even if it s in the main network and i have send token to some peaple?

Comment: Or just the account awner of token should have more ether ?

Comment: I don't understand the logic of the condition there. What are you trying to achieve with it?

Comment: verify if the owner of contract got ether more than amount

Comment: is this any possibilty to modify contract ?

Comment: Contract code is immutable. You need to deploy another contract. I suggest using the testnets to test, so you don't lose real ETH deploying and playing with your contracts